# Instagram options menu from bottom

Tags: android, instagram, menuitem

In the current version of instagram app (Todays date 24-06-2021) ,inside the profile activity/fragment when hamburgur button is pressed (or simply the 3 line icon) now a menu pops up from bottom and can be scroll down by swipe down ,previously when cliked it opens a new fragment/activity

im in love with this animation or a view and im despirat to implement it in my app
but the problem is i dont know what it is called

i want to know what it is exactly and also similar kind of animation or a view is also there in pintrest app

**Screen Shot**

[image]

**Update 1**

how can i navigate to a fragment from a bottom sheet for eg if in my bootomsheet there is 3 textview i  want that if any textView is cliked it should open the respected new fragment i.e if a editprofle textView is clicked it open the editprofile fragment this is how my bottomsheet opens up

**Profile_Fragment.java**

accountSettings the imageView when clicked the bottomSheetopens up

```
accountSettings.setOnClickListener(
                v -> {
                    BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet();
                    bottomSheet.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheet.get Tag());
                }
        );
```

bottom_sheet_profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/slidedownview"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_bottomsheetline"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slidedownview"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:text="@string/settings"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:text="@string/edit_profile"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_profile"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:text="@string/favorite"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/log_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:text="@string/log_out"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its called bottomsheet mate!

Comment: Thank you so much brother you made my day

Comment: no problem. bottomsheet on insta dnt have any animation its the default behavior of bottomsheet.

Comment: ok brother thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Include the following library in your `app.gradle` file.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
```

create custom layout `bottom_sheet_dialog_layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_settings"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Archive"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_archive"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Activity"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_activity"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"/>
....    
....
....
```

in Class file

```
final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_sof);

    TextView settings = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.settings);
    TextView archive = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.archive);
    TextView your_activity = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.activity);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    bottomSheetDialog.show();
```

If you want to click event

```
settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copy is Clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: hey brother please can you check  my updated question on how can i navigate to a fragment from a bottom sheet for eg if in my bootomsheet there is 3 textview i  want that if any textView is cliked it should open the respected new fragment i.e if a editprofle textView is clicked it open the editprofile fragment this is how my bottomsheet opens up

Comment: use ```onClickListener```

Comment: Like this ```settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this , NextActivity.class));
            }
        });```